# Lombok Getter on array index

Tags: java, lombok

Is there a way to use lombok to generate a getters for variables that can be indexed?
For example, if I want:

```
public int getValue(int index) 
{
    return value[i];
}
```

Is there a way to do this with lombok?

Answer (score 3):

With all due respect to you Roel as a dev of Lombok which is great tool btw!

There can be a work-around solution to Mozbi question:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import lombok.experimental.ExtensionMethod;

import org.junit.Test;

@ExtensionMethod({ Extensions.class })
public class LombokTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        int[] intArray = { 5, 3, 8, 2 };

        int actual = intArray.getValue(1);
        assertEquals(3, actual);
    }

}

class Extensions {
    public static int getValue(int[] array, int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

}
```

I propose to write extension and use Lombok's `@ExtensionMethod` annotation instead of `@Getter`(which as Roel noted won't work here). You would need to write a method manually, but you can use it in a very nice way in your code.

Lombok doc https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod.html

Comment: Thanks for your compliments and suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

No, sorry.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.